Brazilian girlfriend traveling with me to the UK
My Brazilian girlfriend is coming to visit me in the UK.
First we will meet in Greece for 2 weeks stay after we have the flight back to London.
If I'm with her in the airport does she still need a return ticket to show?

I don't understand why you think it makes a difference if you are flying into UK on the same flight. She needs to show that she has good reason to leave UK, yet you seem to provide the opposite – attached to you and no return ticket. Aside: have you ever met her?

thanks for your answer

Despite the lack of detail, it smells of a scam. Especially, beware of being asked for money.

Actually she does not need a ticket as such. What she may be asked to prove on arrival is: she’s visiting for tourism; is able to support herself during her trip (or has funding from someone else to support her); has arranged accommodation for her stay; is able to pay for her return or onward journey (or have funding from someone else); and will leave the UK at the end of her visit. A return ticket helps prove she meets these conditions.

It certainly won't hurt to have a return ticket. Otherwise it looks like there's a risk of her overstaying. Remember that border staff have a lot of discretion to admit or refuse entry.

@WeatherVane why does "long-distance relationship" smell of a scam?  There's no indication that they haven't met.  Visiting the mark's home after a two-week vacation together isn't a characteristic of any scam I'm familiar with; have I missed something?

@StuartF in light of the sums that some people pay and the risks that they face to get to the UK by less regular means, the cost of a discarded air ticket is fairly negligible.  The evidential weight of an air ticket is therefore also small.

I presume that you are asking this question because she is planning not to have a return ticket.  This is perfectly acceptable; she's allowed to finalize the details of her departure after arriving.  But if she doesn't have a fixed plan to depart at a certain time, officers are more likely to suspect a potential overstay and refuse to admit her.  They will respond far differently to these two stories:

I don't have a ticket because I intend to return by September 15th, but depending on the results of my relative's medical test next week I may decide to return earlier.

I'm not sure when I'll return because I want to see how well I like it here.


In the first case, there are definite parameters and a maximum intended stay; the second is vague and open ended.
Having a ticket may help in that regard, but it's no guarantee: officers know that someone who plans to overstay may have a ticket that they intend not to use.  If there are other indications of a potential overstay then having a ticket may not be sufficient to overcome them.
On the other hand, if she doesn't have a ticket because she has (for example) a well documented plan to proceed to the continent by surface transportation then there's probably nothing to worry about.
If she won't have a ticket because she does in fact intend to overstay, you should probably rethink the plan altogether.
